# Reversing Many to Many Relationship array

Tags: javascript

```
var x = {one:[1,2,3],two:[3],three:[2]}
var y = {1:['one'], 2:['three', 'one'], 3:['one', 'two']}
```

How can I turn var x to var y? Basically, x is of the form `set->user_arrays`, `set->user_arrays`, when I want to 'reverse' them and get `user->set_arrays`. Preferably the fastest solution, and functional (map etc.)

Comment: You have objects, there is no order to reverse ?

Comment: @adeneo I need to `reverse` the relationship. `type_a->[type_b]` to `type_b->[type_a]`

Comment: Oh, okay! Now I get it. Seems like xdazz has that covered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var x = {one:[1,2,3],two:[3],three:[2]}
var y = {};

for (var k in x) {
  for (var i = 0; i < x[k].length; i++) {
    y[x[k][i]] = y[x[k][i]] || [];
    y[x[k][i]].push(k);
  }
}
```

**[THE WORKING DEMO.](http://jsfiddle.net/8vwXP/)**